# Make "Hats" Opt-in Rather Than Opt-out

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash

To each his own, but there are users for whom "hats" adds no relevant value to this site. On the other hand opting out takes an iota of useful time and attention *from* them annually.

The costs of participation, however small, ought to be taxed to those who wish to play the game — not to those who'd rather not.

---

@CodyGray raised:

> You provide no reason why your time or attention is more valuable than anyone else's.

That's because I don't claim it's more valuable, only equally valuable.

- A person who clicks twice to opt-in is voluntarily giving time in pursuit of something they value.
- A person who clicks twice to opt-out is put in a position where they must give equally valuable time to avoid something they never asked for and do not want.

The first is clearly the more fair outcome.

> Because you're grouchy? Have a Grinch hat:

I wasn't grouchy, but now I'm slightly sad that you felt the need to resort to ad hominem over an evidently unpopular but straight forward feature request.

Comment: *"ought to be taxed to those who wish to play the game — not to those who'd rather not."* - Why?

Comment: Do you mean the two clicks you need to do is taking an "iota of useful time"? :O

Comment: Why not waste the time of people who come to an attention-economy driven site mainly to save time?  In my view the answer is self-evident.  For those for whom it's not, this request is here for anyone to discuss, support or oppose. Have hat it.

Comment: I suppose what I do not understand is how do the hats take any time away from you? It's not like they're hindering your search for posts, hindering you posting anything nor hindering any other action that you can do here. The hats doesn't even require you to dismiss anything. It's just sitting in the corner with a number on it.

Comment: @Scrattle Yep I do indeed mean that switching to opt-in eliminates (at least) two clicks of noise.

Comment: @Scrattle Hats evidently take enough away from enough users that there is an option to not participate.

Comment: How would you know to be able to opt in when the feature becomes available without some sort of banner that would take just as much time, if not more, to review and dismiss? I'm not a big hat fan but this just sounds like sour grapes

Comment: Today I see a snowflake icon, ignoring it takes much less attention than "oh that thing of no interest to me is back, time to opt-out to avoid an even greater stream of irrelevant (to me at least) distractions."

Comment: You can't honestly believe that most people would notice the snowflake icon immediately without some sort of visual prompt in the form of a notification message

Comment: I think it's relatively unimportant that everyone notice it, compared to the main purpose of of the site which is to ask questions about programming and find answers.

Comment: How many mouse clicks, and how much *useful time* did you spend posting this question?

Comment: @Adrian Mole an excellent question. Firstly, I asked on behalf of myself and the like minded.  While my investment here likely exceeds any gain I'd ever realize even if the suggestion were implemented, I care enough about improving the site experience for those who share my point of view that I get something I value for the time and attention spent here. Secondly, I proceed assuming that the status quo is open ended if not challenged. So the collective year-over-year annoyance is potentially infinite.  For, me that's worth pointing out that hats isn't universally loved.

Comment: There is no hats for actual users of the site - the ones who don't have an account and visit the site from search engines. So you opted in to default site's behavior by signing in - disabling hats is *customization* similar to dark/light theme or left nav bar.

Comment: I suppose I should not be surprised that someone who finds hats to be this irritating would also not appreciate my attempt at humor. I hope you find some cheer in *something* this holiday season. Everyone deserves it, especially after this year.

Comment: Agreed @Alexei Levenkov. I believe, by signing in I also opted in to providing feedback and suggesting changes. That is all I've done here. I don't suggest that SO is beyond it's rights to implement opt-out.  Only that opt-in is fair to all.  Opt-out favors participants at the expense of non participants.

Comment: @CodyGray I hope you don't imagine that because I don't find cheer in the same things as you that I'm cheerless.  I'm not sure how irritating you think I find hats, but I'm fairly sure you're over estimating it.  I find "hats" irritating enough to click twice to opt out year after year, which is to say mildly.  If there was an SO game I was enthusiastic about, but a minority had to opt out I'd be making the same suggestion.

Comment: Also worth raising the fact that this event takes place for less than a single month each year, a span which happens to contain the two *least* busy days for the site all year (Christmas and New Years). Between the timing and the UI changes, this event is about as unobtrusive as I can imagine making it while still calling it an "event."

Comment: @zcoop98 this request was prompted by the obtrusivity of the opt-in/opt-out.  A number of comments seem to come at this feature request as if it's an attack on "hats" per se.  My view: any tangential distraction should be opt in.  That it's annoying to a significant minority I think is conceded by the way it's made optional. Vocal dislike for the proposal outweighs support and I'm okay with that.  I've thought about each of the comments and appreciate them.  But none of them persuade me that a game many (but not most) find silly and irrelevant shouldn't be opt-in. C'est la vie.

Comment: I dislike this hat thing, but I also do not want to make the christmas of others worser, who maybe like them. So I have simply chosen to not use them. But I am silent about hat topics. I suggest the same to you.

Answer (score 19):

This strikes me as silly and petty.

The majority of users enjoy having fun at the end of the year with hats. We give you the option to opt out if you so choose, and we don't judge you for it. But we intentionally enable it by default because we think it's fun and most of our users will like it. The developers didn't go through the effort of building this and [fixing all the bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2020+bug), just to have it default to being turned off.

You say:

> …opting out takes an iota of useful time and attention *from* me and each of the like minded annually.

I read this as selfish. Opting *in* would take an iota of useful time and attention away from the ***majority*** of users who like hats and want to have fun. You provide no reason why your time or attention is more valuable than anyone else's. Because you're grouchy? Have a [Grinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinch) hat:

[image]

Oh wait, you don't like hats.

Comment: As I said, to each their own. I wasn't aware that a majority of users actively participate in hats, rather than just forego opting out. Nevertheless a majority imposing a cost for their own "fun" on a minority who prefer utility isn't necessarily a position everyone on a programming Q&A site would hasten to subscribe to.  I regret that you are put off by my differing view.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you __do__ judge me for my preferences, but I'd note that your allusion to the grinch and the fact that you're concerned with my presumed attitude rather than my statements suggest "we don't judge you for it" may not mean what you think it means. As for the effort, I'm sure those who wanted it appreciate it greatly. I stand by my request, which is something I'd appreciate greatly.

Comment: It strikes me as overwhelmingly selfish. I'm not sure how you don't see that. How do you feel about Google Doodles? Are those annoying to you, too? Should they be explicitly opt-in? April Fool's Day pranks? Desktop wallpaper?

Comment: Selfish? On the contrary, I doubt I'm alone in disliking the distraction.  Why else was the effort put into implementing opt-out, if not in recognition of the very issue I'm raising. I get nothing out of it and am asked to pay for the majority who do.  If the majority who value it were opting in they would be getting something out of the two-clicks.  And again, it's not that I think the cost is huge. An iota is something extremely small.

Comment: Google Doodles used to annoy me. I scripted them out so now they don't. I neither pull nor appreciate April Fool's Day pranks. I rather enjoy desktop wallpaper, to that I opt in.

Comment: But I wouldn't, for example, ship a product with an irrelevant wallpaper just for fun and expect my users to change it to something on point, even if a majority of my customers wouldn't mind.

Comment: "This strikes me as...petty". In a user experience, small aggravations are additive. @CodyGray.

Comment: I totally agree with disapproving of April Fool's Day; I was crushed when I learned [Gmail Paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20070413090934/http://mail.google.com/mail/help/paper/more.html) was a scam.